# 'cannot get addfriend' in express while using postrequest

Tags: node.js, express

This is my code app.js code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bp = require("body-parser");
app.use(bp.urlencoded({extended: true}));
var friends = ["babba","lkshjk","kfhkd"];
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.send("homepage");
});
app.get("/friends",function(req,res){
    res.render("friends.ejs",{friends : friends});
});
app.post("/addfriends",function(req,res){
    res.send("works fine");
});
var server = app.listen(2700 ,function() {
    console.log("started");
});
```

and this is friends.ejs code

```
<h1>
    friends list 
</h1>

<% friends.forEach(function(friend){ %>
<li> <%= friend %> </li>
<% }); %>

<form action="/addfriend?" nature="POST">
    <input type="text" ,name="nf" , placeholder="name">
    <button>
        submit
    </button>
</form>
```

i just need "works fine " in my '/addfriend'

but i am getting 
cannot get /addfriend in chrome

this works fine in postman when i try to debug

Comment: Please add an error statement you receive in Google Chrome, that way helping out is easier or the question might already be answered on stack overflow.

Comment: `addfriends` with `s` ending sound.

Answer (score 0):

Your form have to point to the express route.
It should be:

```
<form action="/addfriends" nature="POST">
    <input type="text" ,name="nf" , placeholder="name">
    <button>
        submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Instead of

```
<form action="/addfriend?" nature="POST">
        <input type="text" ,name="nf" , placeholder="name">
        <button>
            submit
        </button>
    </form>
```

You should declare your route equal you did in express route:

```
app.post("/addfriends",function(req,res){
    res.send("works fine");
});
```